# Post-build step in a CDT project with custom exe

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to add a custom exe to the post-build step in Eclipse CDT and my question is: where/how do I supply the path so the post-build step finds the exe?

I have put the exe in the post-build step like this

```
Custom_Exe fist_arg second_arg; arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary "${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}.elf" "${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}.bin" && arm-none-eabi-size "${BuildArtifactFileName}"
```

The exe is located in a sub-folder in the main project folder i.e.

```
"Project_Folder/Preparer/Custom_Exe.exe"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the path before the file relative to the workspace and project name.

```
${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}}/Preparer/Custom_Exe "${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}.bin" v0.71
```