# Eclipse Neon breaks Post-Build with custom exe

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-neon

In one of [my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676801/post-build-step-in-a-cdt-project-with-custom-exe) i asked how to use a custom exe in a post build step in Eclipse Mars.2, this worked flawlessly until i upgraded to Eclipse Neon.

How it looks in Mars.2:

```
C:\Users\Johan.Bregell\workspace-mars\Firmware\Preparer\Custom.exe -F "Firmware.bin"
' '
```

The error I'm getting in Neon is:

```
C:\Users\Johan.Bregell\workspace-neon\Firmware\Preparer\Custom.exe -F "Firmware.bin"
Access is denied.
make[1]: *** [post-build] Error 1
make: *** [Firmware.elf] Error 2
```

Any takes on this ?

Comment: `Access is denied` cannot have many causes... Did you check your file access permissions? Are Eclipse Mars and Neon started with the same level of permissions, with the same user?

Comment: Both programs are started by the same user (on Win 7).  
I have also tried to run Neon as Administrator but with the same result.  Both files also have access right "full control" for my user, admin, and system.

Comment: Ok, that seems strange. And what happens if you launch this command-line manually?

Comment: Normal CMD w/o admin-rights works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It didn't help to change the file access permissions from windows, but I have Cygwin installed and changing the file access permissions with 
"`chmod 777 PostBuildSteps.bat`" command, fixed the issue for me.